# How do I manage changing SNAPSHOT dependencies with Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 0.2.5 with gradle 1.6. I'm collaborating with a developer of a library I'm using, so when he pushes updates to `some-library:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT` I'd like to get it immediately. I can disable caching for changing modules in gradle by setting the resolution strategy as follows:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
```

This works fine for command line builds, but it looks like Android Studio is still using the old version of `some-library-2.1.5-SNAPSHOT`. The only workaround I've been able to get to work is to delete `myproject.iml` and the `.idea` directory and re-import into Android Studio, which is very time consuming and seems unnecessary.

Comment: I'm still having this problem, as of Android Studio 0.2.13. Ever find a good solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the only workaround was to delete the *.iml file and .idea directory and re-import.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround is to delete the `~/.gradle/caches` directory and then sync the project in Android Studio.
This is not ideal since all your dependencies need to be re-downloaded, but its a little less intrusive that re-importing the project into AS as noted by @Joe.

Terminal: rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches

AS: Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files (or hit the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" menu button)

**EDIT**
Did some more researching and [found this little gem](http://blog.james-carr.org/2012/03/14/gradle-deploying-an-artifact-to-the-local-cache/).
Just configure your dependency as such...

```
compile ('groupId:artifactId:X.X.X-SNAPSHOT'){
    changing=true
}
```

Then just run `gradle clean assemble` on the project that has the SNAPSHOT dependency.

I did test to see if a newly added constant became available, and sure enough it worked.

Comment: By default cached changing dependencies are checked for only every 24 hrs. You probably also would have to add configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}. Or add --refresh-dependencies to the gradle call.